# Does process start use another thread?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know when using `Process.Start()` whether a new thread is started? If a new thread is started, this thread, can we control it as foreground or background?

Comment: See this question on altering the priority of a process started using `Process.Start` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374817/how-do-i-start-a-process-with-idle-priority-in-net - which may be relevant to the second part of your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new thread is not created. A new process is (although technically speaking all processes have at least one thread).

Comment: And the thread that the new process has is a newly created thread.

Answer (score 1):

No additional thread is created within the current process - at least not any managed thread that would be visible to you.

Answer (score 1):

Process and Thread, although related, are very different.  Have a look at [What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)