# Run Process.Start() on a background thread?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start a process with idle priority in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374817/how-do-i-start-a-process-with-idle-priority-in-net)

How to run Process.Start on a background thread and give it high priority? I am in a wpf C# application.
Thanks

Comment: Threads cannot contain processes.

Comment: Threads can *start* processes just fine, but you're right to say they can't *contain* processes.

Comment: Why do you need to start it in a background thread?  Starting a process is non-blocking; it doesn't take long at all.  Chances are you could do it from a non-background thread without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Start a process with

```
Process.Start()
```

And then set PriorityClass after you launched it.

About starting Processes from threads see this link: [Async process start and wait for it to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611094/async-process-start-and-wait-for-it-to-finish)

```
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        if(process.WaitForExit(timeout)) {
            // user exited
        } else {
            // timeout
        }
    });
```